# Как найти тег со всеми вложенными тегами того же типа

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения

Есть например структура

```
<div>
text0
    <div class="sidebar menu" id="someID">
        <div class="warning_block">
            <div id="lolID">
                <div>Text1</div>
                <div>Text2</div>
            </div>
            <div id="adsfwe">
                <a href="bla bla">Hello</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    text4
</div>
```

Надо найти блок div, который имеет класс или id с разными значениями, типа sidebar, menu, navigation и который может содержать div вложенные в него.
Пытался составить регулярку, но она находит только до первого или второго (в зависимости от кода, хз почему) закрытия тэга div

```
 <div .*?((class)|(id))="((sidebar.*?)|(menu))".*?>(<div.*?>(?1)*?</div>|.)*?</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста составить верное выражение, или же как-то подправить это

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Переформулируйте свой вопрос. Вам нужно найти `div` элементы в которых есть `class` или `id`?

Comment: Бог парсеров Вас покарает за это :) Возьмите нормальный парсер и там ищите.

Comment: Да, надо найти тег div, в котором есть class или id с разными значениями. А на счёт бога парсеров попробуем договориться)

Comment: Не стоит договариваться, слишком большой оброк запросит. Хоть и было доказано что с помощью регулярок можно распарсить любой валидный HTML, но цена слишком велика (сотни символов регуляроки).

Comment: Понятно. Тогда будем выкручиваться другими средствами

Comment: лучше вместо одного сложного выражения использовать несколько менее сложных - это и отлаживать проще, и потом (через несколько месяцев) понять будет проще.

Comment: @Other, ну не сотни же... Даже до ста можно свободно уложиться. Я уже писал ответ с тэгами, если не найду, то послезавтра напишу что-нибудь, если никто не даст ответ с регулярным выражением.

Comment: Автор, укажите язык в котором требуется регулярное выражение.

Comment: А исходный хтмл так и форматирован отступами, или может быть с неправильным форматированием?

Comment: @ReinRaus, я буду очень удивлён, если валидный парсер HTML5 будет состоять из регулярки менее 100 символов.

Comment: Ну, валидный- нет, но достигающий практически полезных результатов- да. Когда применяешь регулярные выражения, то всегда нужно понимать грани целесообразности: в данном примере, если на входе может быть любая разметка, в том числе и не валидная, то регулярки- не правильное решение. Если же входной текст имеет правильную структуру, то регулярное выражение поможет сократить код, затраченное время и дальнейшую поддержку кода (при условии хорошего знания регулярных выражений).